# How to access column in Dataframe where DataFrame is created by Row

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to pyspark
 Wanted to access column from DataFrame which is created by Row.
Please see below code from my .py file 
It is throwing error AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'product'

```
import findspark

findspark.init("/opt/spark")

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext



productRevenue = Row("product", "category", "revenue")
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("DataFrame Learning") \
    .getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(spark)

productRevenue1 = productRevenue("product", "Cell phone", 6000)
productRevenue2 = productRevenue("Normal", "Tablet", 1500)
productRevenue3 = productRevenue("Mini", "Tablet", 5500)
productRevenue4 = productRevenue("Ultra thin", "Cell phone", 5000)
productRevenue5 = productRevenue("Very thin", "Cell phone", 6000)
productRevenue6 = productRevenue("Big", "Tablet", 2500)
productRevenue7 = productRevenue("Bendable", "Cell phone", 3000)
productRevenue8 = productRevenue("Foldable", "Cell phone", 3000)
productRevenue9 = productRevenue("Pro", "Tablet", 5500)
productRevenue10 = productRevenue("Pro2", "Tablet", 5500)

productRevenueAll = Row(
    productRevenue=[productRevenue1, productRevenue2, productRevenue3, productRevenue4, productRevenue5,
                    productRevenue6, productRevenue7, productRevenue8, productRevenue9, productRevenue10])

dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(productRevenueAll)



filter_df = dataFrame.filter((dataFrame.product=="product") )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a DataFrame from Rows, one approach is to call [`SparkSession.createDataFrame()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame) on a list of Rows.

If you want to create DataFrame like

```
# +----------+----------+-------+
# |   product|  category|revenue|
# +----------+----------+-------+
# |   product|Cell phone|   6000|
# |    Normal|    Tablet|   1500|
# |      Mini|    Tablet|   5500|
# |             ...             |
# +----------+----------+-------+

# with Schema:

# root
#  |-- product: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- category: string (nullable = true)
#  |-- revenue: long (nullable = true)
```

Then rather than having `productRevenueAll` as a Row of Rows, change it to a list of Rows, like:

```py
productRevenueAll = [
    productRevenue1, productRevenue2, productRevenue3, 
    productRevenue4, productRevenue5, productRevenue6, 
    productRevenue7, productRevenue8, productRevenue9,
    productRevenue10,
]

dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(productRevenueAll)

# then use it like:

dataFrame.product
# Column<b'product'>

dataFrame.select(dataFrame.product).show()
# +----------+
# |   product|
# +----------+
# |   product|
# |    Normal|
# |      Mini|
# |   ...    |
# +----------+
```

---

However, in case you really aimed to create a nested structure, like:

```
# +-----------------------------+
# |      productRevenue         |
# +----------+----------+-------+
# |   product|  category|revenue|
# +----------+----------+-------+
# |   product|Cell phone|   6000|
# |    Normal|    Tablet|   1500|
# |             ...             |
# +----------+----------+-------+

# with Schema:

# root
#  |-- productRevenue: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |-- product: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- revenue: long (nullable = true)
```

feed `createDataFrame()` with one-item list, like:

```
productRevenueAllNested = Row(
    productRevenue=[
        productRevenue1, productRevenue2, productRevenue3, 
        productRevenue4, productRevenue5, productRevenue6, 
        productRevenue7, productRevenue8, productRevenue9, 
        productRevenue10,
    ])

dataFrameNested = spark.createDataFrame([productRevenueAllNested]) 

# then access it like
dataFrameNested.printSchema()

dataFrameNested.select(dataFrameNested.productRevenue).show()
# +----------------------+
# |productRevenue.product|
# +----------------------+
# |  [product, Normal,...|
# +----------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @Quar! I tried productRevenueAll as a Row of Rows, change it to a list of Rows worked for me! not sure why question downgraded wtth -1 reputation though 
:-)

Comment: @GaurangPopat Glad it helped :D

Answer (score 1):

You are nesting with Row object which is causing to result `struct` fields.

- Here are the ways you can **createDataFrame** from `Row` object.

---

**`Example:`**

```
#using .toDF to create dataframe
sc.parallelize([productRevenue1, productRevenue2, productRevenue3, productRevenue4, productRevenue5,productRevenue6, productRevenue7, productRevenue8, productRevenue9, productRevenue10]).toDF().show()

#using spark.createDataFrame to create dataframe
spark.createDataFrame([productRevenue1, productRevenue2, productRevenue3, productRevenue4, productRevenue5,productRevenue6, productRevenue7, productRevenue8, productRevenue9, productRevenue10]).show()

#creating dataframe from rdd
productRevenue=sc.parallelize([productRevenue1, productRevenue2, productRevenue3, productRevenue4, productRevenue5,productRevenue6, productRevenue7, productRevenue8, productRevenue9, productRevenue10])

#creating dataframe from list
productRevenue=[productRevenue1, productRevenue2, productRevenue3, productRevenue4, productRevenue5,productRevenue6, productRevenue7, productRevenue8, productRevenue9, productRevenue10]

spark.createDataFrame(productRevenue).show()
#+----------+----------+-------+
#|   product|  category|revenue|
#+----------+----------+-------+
#|   product|Cell phone|   6000|
#|    Normal|    Tablet|   1500|
#|      Mini|    Tablet|   5500|
#|Ultra thin|Cell phone|   5000|
#| Very thin|Cell phone|   6000|
#|       Big|    Tablet|   2500|
#|  Bendable|Cell phone|   3000|
#|  Foldable|Cell phone|   3000|
#|       Pro|    Tablet|   5500|
#|      Pro2|    Tablet|   5500|
#+----------+----------+-------+


dataFrame=spark.createDataFrame(productRevenue)

dataFrame.filter((dataFrame.product=="product") ).show()
#+-------+----------+-------+
#|product|  category|revenue|
#+-------+----------+-------+
#|product|Cell phone|   6000|
#+-------+----------+-------+
```